# Error displaying a view in SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

When I try to access a newly imported subsite view (Import-SPWeb), I receive the following error message:

```
Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Correlation ID: 4b9dfa9f-f682-805f-ad63-6e88b5463728
```

After viewing the log file, I find the following match with the Correlation ID:

```
10/19/2021 10: 25: 33.99 w3wp.exe (0x0638) 0x4A18 SharePoint Foundation DistributedCache air4a Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to get token from distributed cache for '0) .w | s-1-5-21-1701066693- 419617663-1970593239-500 '. (This is expected during the process warm up or if data cache Initialization is getting done by some other thread). 4b9dfa9f-f682-805f-ad63-6e88b5463728 "

10/19/2021 10: 25: 33.99 w3wp.exe (0x0638) 0x4A18 SharePoint Foundation DistributedCache air4b Monitorable Token Cache: Reverting to local cache to get the token for '0) .w | s-1-5-21-1701066693- 419617663-1970593239-500 '. 4b9dfa9f-f682-805f-ad63-6e88b5463728
```

I have tried to open the page with the SharePoint Designer and save but the error persists.
Please, I appreciate any help to fix the error.
Thank you

Comment: Per the ULS, please go to CA -> Manage services on server and check if Distributed Cache service is started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! 
There is no Distributed Cache service on that server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` to add an instance of the distributed cache service to a local server. Reference: [Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance?view=sharepoint-ps).

Answer (score 0):

Launched the following command on my SharePoint2013 server:

```
Get-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedLogonTokenCache
```

To consult the Distributed Cache a service and it returns the following:

```
ChannelInitializationTimeout : 60000  ConnectionBufferSize       : 131072
MaxBufferPoolSize            : 1073741824  
MaxBufferSize                : 33554432  MaxOutputDelay          : 2  
ReceiveTimeout               : 60000  ChannelOpenTimeOut         : 3000  
RequestTimeout               : 300  MaxConnectionsToServer       : 4
```

The service is started and continue equal. We have a big problem since we cannot visualize the content

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).